# How do I remove spaces from a processed target string using sed?

Tags: sed

I search in .cpp files and remove everything after the “delimiter string” up to and including the first “,” using this sed command.

```
sed -re 's/(GetValue[(])[^,]*,/\1/' *.cpp
```

Thus…

```
abc.GetValue(SomeString,      SecondParam);
```

Becomes…

```
abc.GetValue(      SecondParam);
```

**Question:**

But, how do I remove these spaces in the strings I find without removing all other spaces in the file ?

This removes spaces from the whole file e.g. **sed -re 's/(GetValue[(])[^,]*,/\1/;s/ //g ' *.cpp**

Comment: Add a match for spaces to the pattern in your sed command after the comma.

Comment: I Can't get that to work, It does the whole file. e.g. sed -re 's/(GetValue[(])[^,]*,/\1;/s/ //g' This does the whole file.

Comment: I said "to the pattern" not in its own match/pattern. `'s/(GetValue[(])[^,]*, */\1/'`

Comment: Thanks ! I'm really new to using sed and I still trying to learn the pattern matching rules. This works nice ! Thanks again.

Comment: Using `[(]` to escape is slightly ingenious and threw me off when parsing your regex. It's more traditional to use a backslash: `\(`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to match the spaces in your pattern. You are already matching everything else.

Just add `*` or `\s*` or whatever appropriate match to your pattern.

```
sed -re 's/(GetValue[(])[^,]*, */\1/' *.cpp
```